# Where is my saddle in Beecher's Hope?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

I can’t seem to find my saddle in Beecher's Hope after I took it off my horse. The map says it’s in the house but I can’t find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same happened to me. Go to the fast travel desk in your room. Travel to Blackwater and visit the stable there. Exit the stable and your saddle will be back on your horse.

Answer (score 1):

There is a glitch, its under the house.. on the ground where the old shack stood..

Answer (score 0):

When I have lost my horse and saddle I'm pretty sure I was able to retrieve them both by saving, reloading, then going to the stable. Have you checked the stable?

Comment: Wonder where it’s at in the house makes no sense to me

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the place where you can tie your horse outside your house and switch horses, you can switch horses and then the saddle will be back.  Kind of obnoxious but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Well for me when I took off the saddle it was on the roof of the house for some reason. I don't think that there is any way to get onto the roof tho to get it down.